# Drupal Views - Ajax Error Alert Box From Hell

Tags: ajax, drupal, view, alert

Anything I do in views that would normally use ajax to open up a new form to modify properties of that action is giving me an alert box of what looks like the code that should be loading with ajax:

[image]

Comment: Did you add a newer version of jQuery from the one that came with Drupal?

Comment: Wow, that's exactly it. Forgot I was playing around with colorbox and manually added a newer version. Toss it in as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add a newer version of jQuery to your Drupal install it can create problems with AJAX and Views UI.

I have found myself in the exact same position before. I reverted back to the original jQuery version shipped with Drupal and everything was back to normal.

Comment: Depending on what version of jQuery you need, you may be able to use the jQuery Update module: https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update

Answer (score 8):

There can be another source of this problem (if the previous comments didn't solve it):
the **[Theme developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer)** module.

This is a really helpful module for theming and debugging, but when having it enabled, it can also produce weird AJAX error messages, similar to the one in the question when trying to set different parameters in Views field settings.

As the project's page suggests: ***"Enable it when needed, and disable it afterwards."***

Comment: I'll second this! Thanks. I had an error being thrown with Views/ip_geoloc and wasted 2 hours+ I noticed Devel was later at 7x.1.5 compared to 7x.1.3 which worked on another project. Once I disabled the 1.5 mould, the errors went away. They were code http 200 Ajax as such: <<An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /sitename/admin/structure/views/ajax/display/asset_map_location/page/style_options
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: Notice: Undefined index... etc etc>>  I hope this helps someone in future. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it happen too when the AJAX widget (for example, Panels) is trying to access an invalid, or no longer valid menu callback. I would search the menu router for things like:

```
select * from menu_router where path like '%ajax%'; and
select * from menu_router where path like '%ajax/add%';
```

Then make sure that the function mentioned in the `page_callback` column exists.

Changed permissions can also cause this problem.
Check what the `access_callback` column says, and try debugging that path `(/admin/build/views/ajax/add-item/community/default/field)` with different user roles to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: I just figured out that another theme that might cause such a behaviour is the **ThemeKey** module (which - dispite of that- does a great work in what it is intended to...). At least disabling it at my site did the trick.